# CQRS - Command/Query single parameter

Tags: cqrs

All the examples showcasing the CQRS pattern always have 0 or 1 parameter.

For example:

```
public class MyCommand
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class MyCommandHandler
{
    public void Handle(MyCommand myCommand)
    { ... }
}
```

Assuming we are calling the handle directly is there is any reason besides the implementation details?

I'm aware of the advantages of having a single parameter, like encapsulating all the required data to perform the action and also making it easier to serialize if we have to work with Queues of Q/C, validation, etc..

But is it "wrong" to have multiple parameters in the handler?

Answer (score 0):

> But is it "wrong" to have multiple parameters in the handler?

No; it's *tradeoffs*.

When we have handlers with incompatible signatures, then *composing* handlers -- for instance, creating a handler with some cross cutting concerns -- takes more work because of the number of variations required.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not, I would say that it is sometimes advisable to use multiple parameters to separate concerns. Because you might have traceID, correlationID, or other types of technical data that you don't want to combine with business data. When you send a request, you are using headers, so when sending a message for handling, headers can be used as well

```java
public class MyCommandHandler
{
    public void Handle(MyCommand myCommand, MyHeader $header, MySecondHeader $secondHeader)
}
```

Also, if you don't want to inject dependencies in constructor for whatever reason, it is ok to inject them as parameters.